# catch content in the same box into array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have HTML like :

```
<div id='main-post' class='my-post'>
$start
   content 1
$end
$start
   content 2
$end
$start
   content 3
$end
$start
   content 4
$end
</div>
```

Now, I want parse the textual content of `$main-post` between each `$start` to `$end` block into an array and get the following result:

```
   thecontent[1] == "content 1"
   thecontent[2] == "content 2"
   ...
```

Comment: I don't get it, what's `$start` and `$end`? They're not HTML, for sure.

Comment: @Jack: yes. It is special content.

Comment: @happi if you don't ellaborate people can't really help you at all. How is this rendered? what other elements come into play?

Comment: @Nico: sorry if my question make everyone confuse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a regular expression problem of matching blocks between `$start` and `$end`:

```
var content = $('#main-post').text(),
re = /\$start([\s\S]*?)\$end/g,
thecontent = [];

while ((match = re.exec(content)) !== null) {
    thecontent.push($.trim(match[1]))
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NCvwu/1/)

Since JavaScript doesn't have a "dot match all" modifier, I'm using the `[\s\S]` trick to accomplish the same thing.

**Old answer**

Stabbing in the dark here, but if you want to fetch the textual content of each child node under `#main-post`:

```
var thecontent = $('#main-post')
    .children()
    .map(function() {
        return this.textContent || this.innerText || '';
    })
    .get();
```

Comment: I doubt this is what he was asking though, but I'm surprised by your brave attempt at answering his "question"

Comment: @Jack: Thank you. But thecontent return undefined like this : http://jsfiddle.net/NCvwu/

Comment: I believe `$start` and `$end` are self-made identifiers (just text) and he wants to capture anything in between them. My regex skills aren't awesome...something like `\$start(.+)\$end` and store the captured groups to the array.

Comment: @happi yes, because he solved a different problem. You should attempt to understand his code rather than just pointing out that it is undefined. It's not hard to get the gist of it.

Comment: @m59: your right. I want catch that.

Comment: @happi So, this is actually a regular expression question then?

Comment: Since in your case, you have no children under #main-post, use $('#main-post').text() to get the raw text, then do some string manipulation to split that by your custom delimiters $start/$end.

Comment: @Jack: yes. you have misunderstanding in my question. my mistake. sorry. can you update your answer. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but I thought I'd post this anyway. It's somewhat fragile because it assumes the raw text structure (with custom delimited blocks $start/$end) is cleanly in order), but it should work with the sample provided in the question.

```
var raw_content = $('#main-post').text();
var the_content = raw_content.split(/(?:\s*\$(?:start|end)\s*)+/).slice(1, -1);
```

PS: As a bonus, I learned today that if the regexp used in string.split() contains capturing parentheses, they would be part of the resulting array! So I had to add (?:) explicitely to make them non-capturing.

Comment: +1 Though, personally, I prefer matching over splitting simply because it's easier to reason with :)

Comment: Interesting behaviour of the capturing parentheses, quite unlike pcre whereby you must explicitly specify that intent :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = document.getElementById('main-post');

var text = div.textContent;

var theContent = [];
text.replace(/\$start([\s\S]*?)\$end/g, function(s, match) {
  theContent.push(match.trim());
});

console.log(theContent);
```

[**Live demo here (click).**](http://jsbin.com/ojUHaYU/1/edit)

Comment: You like the `[\s\S]` trick? ;-)

Comment: @Jack yeah! It was cleaner than the junk I did so I figured I should update since we have different approaches `exec` vs `replace`. Good job! You got my upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

`<html>`
`<head>`
`<title>catch content in the same box into array?</title>`
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript">`

```
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            var thecontent = [];  
            thecontent[0] = "nuovo content";  
            thecontent[1] = "nuovo content";  
            thecontent[2] = "nuovo content";  
            thecontent[3] = "nuovo content";  

            /* The same as above  
            var thecontent = [  
                "nuovo content 1",  
                "nuovo content 2",  
                "nuovo content 3",  
                "nuovo content 4"  
            ]  
            */  
            $(".content").each(function(index) {  
                console.log($(this).html());  
                $(this).html(thecontent[index]);  
            });  
        });  
</script>
```

`</head>`
`<body>`
    `<div id='main-post' class='my-post'>`
    `<div class="content">content 1</div>`
        `<div class="content">content 2</div>`
        `<div class="content">content 3</div>`
        `<div class="content">content 4</div>`
    `</div>`
`</body>`
`</html>`

Answer (score 1):

### First scenario

If your `$start` and `$end` are DOM nodes, and form a syntax like this:

```
<div>
    <span>$start</span>
    content 1
    <span>$end</span>
    <span>$start</span>
    content 2
    <span>$end</span>
</div>
```

You can do the following

```
var postEl = document.getElementById('main-post');
var thecontent = [];
for (var i in postEl.childNodes) {
    if (postEl[i] instanceof Text) thecontent.push(postEl[i]);
}
```

That will get every text node that is a direct child of the parent div and put it in your array.

### Second scenario

If your `$start` and `$end` are opening and closing tags respectively, like this:

```
<div>
    <span>
        content 1
    </span>
    <span>
        content 2
    </span>
</div>
```

then you can do the following:

```
var currentElement = document.getElementById('main-post').firstElementChild;
var thecontent = [];
while (currentElement.nextElementSibling) {
    thecontent.push(currentElement.nextElementSibling.innerHTML);
    currentElement = currentElement.nextElementSibling;
}
```

That will get all the contents of the direct children of the parent node and put them in your array.

If this did not answer your question, you should provide a much more detailed example with your question, and perhaps even a demo.