# Script does not run if adding another ID beside exist ID

Tags: jquery

I gave a question in a previous post.  Here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793641/catch-content-in-the-same-box-into-array).

It runs ok. But when I put another `ID` beside exist id, it cannot run. Everyone can say why and fix it for me. thanks.

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NCvwu/3/)

Here is [my edit](http://jsfiddle.net/NCvwu/4/) (adding more id)

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Happi,

you cannot have multiple ids to a HTML element.

You can take reference from her http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10

Answer (score 1):

The ID attribute of an element must be unique across the document, see [Global Attributes on the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-id).

> This attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique
>   in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when
>   linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with
>   CSS).

Because of the one-to-one relationship between the element and the ID, it does not make sense to add multiple IDs to a single element.

The [specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute) also states-

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home
>   subtree and must contain at least one character. **The value must not
>   contain any space characters**.

If you want add an attribute for styling purposes, to select the element using jQuery/native JavaScript, or for a state that changes visual appearance then you should consider adding a CSS class - an element can have zero or more classes and classes can be duplicated within a single document.

If you are working on a high-performance application, then you might want to use [data- attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to add state information to the elements as this will not trigger a repaint. The data attribute could also be used as a selector for jQuery or native JavaScript querySelector methods.